# django registration redux не работает почта

Tags: python, django

setting.py

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS= 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN= True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/home'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = '' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

почта прихожит от webmaster@localhost хотя SMTP настроен, почта стоит на домене. Как сделать чтобы сообщения приходили с моей почты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо в конце файла добавить DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'email' где email это ваша корпоративная почта